# DTLS 1.2 Key Expansion

Tags: tls

I am using **DTLS 1.2** and my cipher is **TLS_ECDHE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

According to RFC 5246([RFC 5246 key calculation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-26)) i am calculating keys but i can not find the size of these keys in this RFC.

What is the size of following keys.

1- Client_Write_Mac_Key

2- Server_Write_Mac_Key

3- Client_Write_key

4- Server_Write_key

5- Client_Write_IV

6- Server_Write_IV

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5288. The keys are obviously 128 bit for AES-128. You're missing the authentication scheme in your TLS ciphersuite string.

Comment: but what is the size of MAC key?

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a GCM-based ciphersuite, there is no MAC key. If the tool insists on a size, give it 0.

See RFC5246 section 6.2.3.3 (which discusses AEAD ciphers, of which GCM is one example); it explicitly states that, in this case, no MAC key is used.

In addition, the IV sizes are 4 bytes; these 4 bytes are combined with the 8 bytes from the TLS record to form the 12 byte GCM nonce; see RFC5288 second 3.

And, of course, the encryption keys for GCM128 is 16 bytes, yielding a total of:

> 1- Client_Write_Mac_Key - 0 bytes
>
> 2- Server_Write_Mac_Key - 0 bytes
>
> 3- Client_Write_key - 16 bytes
>
> 4- Server_Write_key - 16 bytes
>
> 5- Client_Write_IV - 4 bytes
>
> 6- Server_Write_IV - 4 bytes

Comment: I think this answer misses the 4/8/12 byte nonce/IV calculation. And of course the size of the encryption keys, although those should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: thanks for the reminder -- I initially just answered his plea of 'but what is the size of the MAC key', and forgot that he asked for the rest of the sizes as well...

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: when i compute master secret its size is 48 bytes and according to your answer i need 16 + 16 + 4 + 4 = 40 bytes key. Do i expand the key according to RFC 5246 Section 6.3 or use the 40 bytes of master secret?

Comment: @poncho do i need do expand master secret or not?

Comment: @AhsanYounis No you expand the key. The entropy of the master secret may not be completely well distributed. The PRF makes sure that it is.